# function takes an element and a list and checks if the length of the list is equal to the element

Tags: prolog

i am a beginner  in Prolog and i am trying to do a function takes an element and a list and checks if the length of the list is equal to the element.

Here what I did :-

```
iseq(X,Y) :- 
    lent(L,X) =:= Y. 

lent([],0).
lent([H|T],N):- lent(T,N1),N is N1 + 1.
```

"lent" return the length of a list and "iseq" checks if two numbers are equal.

it shows error :

```
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,lent/2),(=:=)/2)
```

now I know that it is possible to write in a shorter and more clean way but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the predicate wrongly: `lent(L,X) =:= Y` won't work because `lent(L,X)` does not return a value: it is not a function. Being a predicate, it just succeeds or fails (or maybe throws) based on the arguments it has been passed. It may also refine in the passed arguments some more, i.e. replace any variables therein with actual values.

Additionally, there is no need to do arithmetic comparison. Just ask `lent/2` whether `Length` is indeed the correct length of `List`:

```
iseq(List,Length) :- lent(List,Length). 

lent([],0).
lent([_H|T],N) :- lent(T,N1),N is N1 + 1. 

:- begin_tests(lent).

test("empty list",true(Length == 0)) :- iseq([],Length).
test("1-element list",true(Length == 1)) :- iseq([a],Length).
test("2-element list",true(Length == 2)) :- iseq([a,b],Length).

:- end_tests(lent).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: lent ... done
% All 3 tests passed
true.
```

And now you can strongly fix `lent/2` by NOT computing `N is N1 + 1` AFTER the recursive call. Doing that is bad because it forces the stack to grow. Try it!